# maintain proportions on css fluid layout

Tags: css, image, fluid-layout

I've set my layout in percentage but my div contain an image that need to mantain proportions.
I've calculate, for example, to mantain 2 : 1 so width = 300px, height = 150px.

how I can do this only with css?
can I read the percentage and divide this to 2?

Answer (score 0):

For images to maintain proportion have to define only one dimension.

So if you set the width to 300px and height to auto, it will maintain the ratio..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`width:66.67%` and `width:33.33%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the percent for the image as if you define the image width in percent it will dimense to it's parent div width. So you must define the width in pixel for the image as you want the original image size proportionally. But if you want to proportionate the width of div you can use then percent. And to proportionate the image just define the width and not the height, this will proportionate the image as it's original size.